# babel: decimal separator is missing when `shorthands=off` is set

Tags: babel, spanish

With this simple input:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
  A number: $10.58$.
\end{document}
```

The resulting pdf looks like:
[image]

The decimal comma is missing.

How can I get the decimal separator back but keeping the `shorthands=off` parameter?

(This is actually Pandoc disabling the shorthands in its LaTeX template).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even if you get a good work-around for this, you may still want to contact the author or `babel-spanish`: https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-spanish about this, it certainly looks like a bug to me (I can't read the documentation: It's in Spanish...)

Comment: Things seem to work with `\usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `babel-spanish` module sets `` \mathcode`.="8000 `` notwithstanding `shorthands=off` and it turns out that the active period used in math expands to `\es@useshorthand .`, which is an obvious problem because shorthands have been turned off. Eventually, this leads to doing `\csname active@char.\endcsname` and this is undefined leading, by TeX rule, to `\relax`.

This seems like a bug.

The option `es-nodecimaldot` makes things so that the period is not math active, so it seems the right thing to do until the bug is fixed.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[
  spanish,
  shorthands=off,
  es-nodecimaldot,
]{babel}
\begin{document}

\the\mathcode`.

A number: $10.58$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `es-nodecimaldot` we get

[image]

Comment: Seems a bug, indeed.